# Eigenspace of A Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question:**

How to find the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to all the different real eigenvalues.

This matrix only three real eigenvalues, $\lambda = 5, 1, 1$. Step by step, how would I go about finding the eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue, say, $\lambda = 1$?

A = $\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & -1\\
1 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & -2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks!

Comment: It has two real eigenvalues with one repeated, $\lambda_{1, 2, 3} = 1, 1, 5$ (unless it is written incorrectly). Also, you can find three linearly independent eigenvectors, no generalized or chaining required.

Comment: I will correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $(A-I)x=0$ yields \begin{align}x_1+2x_2-x_3&=0\\ x_1+2x_2-x_3&=0\\-x_1-2x_2+x_3&=0,
\end{align} 
and hence $$x_1+2x_2=x_3. $$ It follows that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is the span of $$\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}. $$ Similarly, $(A-5I)x=0$ yields 
\begin{align}
-3x_1+2x_2-x_3&=0\\
x_1-2x_2-x_3&=0\\
-x_1-2x_2-3x_3&=0,
\end{align}
and hence $$x_3=-x_1,\quad x_2=x_1. $$ It follows that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=5$ is the span of $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: How do you get from step 2 to the span corresponding to $\lambda = 1$? I can figure out how you did it for $\lambda = 5$ once you answer for $\lambda = 1$

Comment: A linear equation of the form $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=0$ is a plane  and so is the span of two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. I just let $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$ to find two vectors on that plane.